# Overriding a method with different parameters in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

While reading the method overriding part of the Typescript documentation, I came across something interesting. Normally the method of base class would not be referenced while overriding method in javascript. But it is different in typescript.

**Example**

```js
class Base {
  greet() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {

  /* 
  Property 'greet' in type 'Derived' is not assignable to the same   property in base type 'Base'.
  Type '(name: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() =>     void'.
  */
  greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello, ${name.toUpperCase()}`);
  }
}
```

Actually, it can be done this way.

```js
class Derived extends Base {
  greet(name?: string) {
    if (name === undefined) {
      super.greet();
    } else {
      console.log(`Hello, ${name.toUpperCase()}`);
    }
  }
}
```

But why? Is this a pattern? Do I have to do it this way when overriding method?

Comment: You're not overriding, you're overloading. Different operations.

Answer (score 0):

"Assignable" in typescript simply means that the parameter and return types overlap.

You have these signatures:

```
greet(): void;
greet(name: string): void;
```

Since the parameter types don't overlap, typescript warns you that the signature is not assignable to the base method.

If you change the second method to `greet(name?: string): void;`

then the parameter types overlap (`?` means a parameter is optional)) and typescript doesn't need to warn you, because you need to manually check if `name` is available or not.